# Get Symbol for ReferenceLocation

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm using the `SymbolFinder` to find all references to a certain type in my solution like this:

```
ISymbol typeOfInterest = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName(
    "System.Reflection.PropertyInfo");
var references = SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(typeOfInterest, solution).Result;
foreach (var reference in references)
{
    // reference.Locations => symbol?
}
```

This part is working fine, the `SymbolFinder` returns correct `ReferenceLocations` (upon manual inspection). I'm actually interested in the symbols at these locations to get more (semantic) information about the references, so I can filter upon / work with it (e.g. only work on properties).

There seems to be very little public information on Roslyn yet and I couldn't find anything *working* with the results of `SymbolFinder` in the samples of the SDK Preview. So here is my question: Is it possible to get the symbol corresponding to a `ReferenceLocation`? How?

Comment: What do you mean by "corresponding to"? A reference to symbol X will be a reference corresponding to the symbol X. Now that seems too simple to be what you're asking for. Are you wondering what symbol is doing the referencing? That is, what method body it is occurring in, for example?

Comment: @Neal: exactly! I'm looking for property declarations of a certain type (e.g. `PropertyInfo`) inside all classes within my solution. I think Jason's answer / hint to the enclosing symbol is what I'm looking for or at least very close..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, there isn't strictly a "symbol" at any of these locations, at least no innate concept of that. What you can do is take that Location, and find the enclosing symbol. You can take the location's `SyntaxTree` and get a `Document`. From there, call `GetSemanticModelAsync`, and then call `ISemanticModel.GetEnclosingSymbol`.

As an example, here's some (internal) code that does this for FAR itself: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/748d6ab1b504ceee0c29f132fdcbe2a777aa88ea/src/Workspaces/Core/Portable/FindSymbols/ReferenceLocationExtensions.cs#L67-L101

Comment: Can you please explain that `Dictionary<ISymbol, List<Location>>` return type?  In my scenario, I'm looking for the invocations of the `SetMethod` of a certain type's instance-level property; I want to know the various resulting types of the ExpressionSyntax node that is being assigned/passed to this method.  So I need to get the AssignmentExpressionSyntax or the InvocationExpressionSyntax or whatever it is for that location, get the Right side or the argument ExpressionSyntax's resulting type.

Comment: When you do SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync, you give it a single symbol, but we may cascade to a number of symbols. For example, if you search for a virtual method, we will cascade to overrides of that method. Searching on a type will cascade to the constructor so "new Foo()" is also found. For each symbol, we then give the list of location references to that symbol.

Comment: Sadly, this approach doesn't work for all usage cases. For instance, if you use semanticModel.GetEnclosingSymbol() on a field's NamedType position, you don't get the Field symbol, you get the NamedType of the class the field is in. Similarly, if you use GetEnclosingSymbol() on a base class NamedType position, you don't get the class doing the inheriting, you get the containing namespace instead.  Ugh. (With version 1.1.1 of Roslyn)

Comment: @JasonMalinowski, Specifically, this seems related to the issues discussed in: [VB.Net Roslyn GetEnclosingSymbol issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1290). Any additional ideas about how to do this kind of work with Roslyn?

Comment: @BillTutt: By the sound of it, GetEnclosingSymbol is not what you want. You should ask a new question (do not use comments) and clarify what you're trying to build and then we can help you.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski, I went and created a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35918908/symbol-from-referencelocation/35947351#35947351), and found at least another way of accomplishing my goal in the answer section.

Comment: The link is broken. How do you get the "position" from the ReferenceLocation object?

Comment: @zezba9000: updated the link for what I think corresponds to the original link. Hope this helps!